# Terminate or bust natted connection

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have a problem with natted connection on linux.

I'm using Debian 10, and iptables to do some SNAT to force all my packets outgoing from eth0 to a specific UDP port to use a specific IP attached to eth0 :

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p udp --dport 38041 -j SNAT --to-source 10.230.0.1
```

But sometimes, the source IP gets redistributed and it changes. Say in my example it goes from 10.230.0.1 to 10.230.0.4. The IP is reassigned to eth0, the iptables rules is deleted and a new iptables rules is added (with the right IP)

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p udp --dport 38041 -j SNAT --to-source 10.230.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p udp --dport 38041 -j SNAT --to-source 10.230.0.4
```

When I look my iptables rules, everything looks OK :

```
#iptables -t nat -nL
...
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:38041 to:10.230.0.4
```

But it's not working. When I look my traffic with tcpdump :

```
#tcpdump -i eth0 udp port 38041
21:21:25.829610 IP 10.253.0.1.38041 > xx.xx.xx.xx.38041:  [...payload...]
```

I tried to play with netstat-nat but I didn't managed to get anything from it.

The old IP is still used in the natted connexion. I cannot undestand why. And it's happening on multiple servers so I don't think this is some kind of a glitch.

Do you know how the proper way to bust that rule for good and replace it with the new one ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `conntrack -D` to delete the NAT states related to those connections, or wait until they time out after inactivity.

iptables' NAT is always stateful – each packet stream goes through the `nat` table *only once*, and the system remembers the translation afterwards. (This is done for TCP connections as well as connectionless UDP flows both, and is necessary in order to correctly "un-NAT" response packets, as there are no explicit iptables rules to make that happen.)

NAT states are stored in the kernel's *conntrack* subsystem. As long as conntrack has a record for your particular source→destination, it will always apply the same translation, ignoring your iptables `nat` rules.

Comment: Wow thanks, it works AND I understand. To help future readers have a look at this question to delete specific conntrack entries : https://serverfault.com/questions/367626/delete-specific-conntrack-entries